# ViewPager.PageTransformer showing error ViewPager cant rersolved to a type i am using androidsupportv4 jar revision 9

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-support-library

I am unable to get the androidsupportv4 revision 11 from eclipse by using **AndroidTools** enter **AddSupportLibrary**  can anyone please tell me how to get it from Eclipse why i am not able to get it.I know its `ViewPager.PageTransformer` added in **androidsupportv4.jar** revision 11.is there any way to fix it..Because i have some problem with my network i am  not able to get or install new version.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well i fixed this problem i downloaded a new version of **Android SDK ADT Bundle** and i extract  the android supportlibraryv 4 revision 13  from the path inside **SDK/extras/android/support/v4** cheers happy coding!!!